# How to return Array of data from reducer to container?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux

Following is the reducer file where I am returning data to Container:

```
import FETCH_MEDIAID from '../actions/index';

export default function(state = [], action){
  console.log('Action Received', action);
  switch(action.type){
    case FETCH_MEDIAID:
      return action;
  }
  return state;
}
```

My Get Request is the following (I want to return Media Metadata about the Instagram content once user inserts Instagram content url in input field):

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const FETCH_MEDIAID = 'FETCH_MEDIAID';

const RootURL= `https://api.instagram.com/oembed?url=`;

export function fetchMediaID(shortcode){

  const url = `${RootURL}${shortcode}`;

  const request = axios.get(url);

  console.log('Request is: ', request);

  return {
    type: FETCH_MEDIAID,
    payload: request
  };
}
```

I am new with handling API responses.

Output Component:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

 class Output extends React.Component {

  renderMediaid(metaData){
     return(
       <tr>
         <td>{metaData.media_id}</td>
       </tr>
     );
   }
  render(){
    return(
      <table className='table table-hover'>
        <tbody>
           {this.props.mediaid.map(this.renderMediaid)}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      );
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {mediaid: state.mediaid};
}


    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Output);
```

Comment: 1) are you using then or a async/await on your AJAX request?
2) you're going to want to probably look at action.payload.data

Comment: Hi @greybarkans,

1: I am not using then. I think this is a async request using axios library. 
2:  If I use action.payload.data I get console errors while using that data in container

Comment: Where is the code that creates the action type and payload in your function fetchMediaId ?
Are you returning action.payload.data in your reducer or just 'action' ?

Are you checking to if the object of action.payload.data matches the logic in your container ?

Comment: In your reducer you need to return the state updated in an immutable fashion with the desired data that would go to your connected container component. Right now you are returning the action rather than the updated state in the branch of the case statement. Also you may need some kind of middleware in your action to dispatch the action only when the async HTTP call has completed. Additionally you may want to create another action representing the success response, so a request action and a success action. This could be approached in so many ways.

Comment: The reactjs/redux async [example](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/tree/master/examples/async) can be a great starting point for the overall approach to handling async actions in redux as well as updating state immutably in the reducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> switch(action.type){
>   case FETCH_MEDIAID:
>     return action;
> }
> ```

This almost never happens in a reducer. For one thing, your action is a plain old JavaScript object and you've specified that the default state for this reducer is an array. You almost certainly want to return an array that's being carried as a *payload* on the action. So something like:

```
case FETCH_MEDIAID:
  return [ ...action.payload ]
```

is more likely, assuming `payload` is an array.

> ```
> const request = axios.get(url);
> return {
>   type: FETCH_MEDIAID,
>   payload: request
> };
> ```

Axios is promise-based. At the time you return the object literal, `request` will be a promise but the async operation (making the actual request to the server) is unlikely to have completed. More usual would be:

```
return axios.get(url)
  .then(response => ({
    type: FETCH_MEDIAID,
    payload: response
  });
```

Note that if `response` is not a simple array (perhaps it has a `data` property with an array on it?) then you'll need to modify your reducer to deal with this, or assign `response.data` as the `payload` value.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help @richchurcher. Now I am not getting any error but still my markup is still not generating any output. where do you think I am going wrong. See above I have updated the code for the container that is generating output.